# Open JavaScript file from WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I'm using the WebStorm IDE, and I want to open a JavaScript file from the IDE but the only configurations are for debugging and xslt. So is there a wa to create my own configurations
. In moment I start my file like using this task in my .profile:

```
function plask() { 
  /Applications/PlaskLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/Plask.app/Contents/MacOS/plask "$@" 
}
```

Could create a configuration that use this task to open the file in the plask app?

Comment: Are you trying to *execute* or *run* a JavaScript file?  Because you can simply open files and edit them from within the IDE.  I don't think there's any extra steps involved.

Comment: Yes the plask app run the JS file using node, so I want to start them from the ide.

Comment: Have you [checked out the WebStorm documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html), which explains how to create a run configuration?

Comment: Yes but it's only for the two default types. No explanation how to create own run configurations

Comment: That link I included says *right there*: **To create a run/debug configuration**, and includes step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Sure, but you it describes how to create a new configuration based on the 2 given, which not fit my needs, as I don't want to run a JavaScript in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try the early access version of the [NodeJS plug-in](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?webide&id=6098).